# How to show the result form getting array?

Tags: php, html, sql

Database :

```
  --> product table
    P_id    P_name          P_uploadKey
    1       Cemera          7365
    2       Notebook        7222
    3       Monitor         7355
    4       Printer         7242

    --> buy table
    B_id   P_id      B_name      date 
    1      1,3,4     somchai   12/3/2016
    2      2,3       kri       12/3/2016
```

This sql to show the find id on buy table where `$_GET['B_id'] = '2'` :

```
 $bid = $_GET['B_id'];

    $sqlB ="select * from buy where B_id ='$bid' ";
    $Recordset2 = mysql_query($sqlB, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
```

And this sql code to show the result what is they buy, by get the `$row_Recordset2['P_id']  like a 2,3` from code above :

```
$pid = $row_Recordset2['P_id'];
$sqlp ="select * from buy where P_id ='$pid' ";
$Recordset3 = mysql_query($sqlp, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3);
do {
echo $row_Recordset3['P_name']. "<br>";
}  while ($row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3));
```

I want the to show like this, how we edit it:

```
Notebook
Monitor
```

Comment: Google `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` perhaps.

Comment: now just show Notebook only

Comment: Your `$row_Recordset2['P_id']` variable contains comma separated values. You need to convert them into array using `expload` and the process array to get details from `buy` table or as @Epodax suggested you can use `JOIN, LEFT JOIN` as well

Comment: STOP USING MYSQL_* use mysqli_* or PDO instead !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer i can do it.

```
$pid = $row_Recordset2['P_id'];

$array =  explode(',', $pid);

foreach ($array as $item) {


$sqlp ="select * from buy where P_id ='$item' ";
$Recordset3 = mysql_query($sqlp, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3);
do {
echo $row_Recordset3['P_name']. "<br>";

}  while ($row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3));    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below,

```
$sqlp ="select * from product where P_id IN '($pid)'";
```

instead of

```
 $sqlp ="select * from buy where P_id ='$pid' ";
```